# SpringSecurity without having to define the filter section in the web.xml

Tags: filter, spring-security, web.xml

I'd like to use SpringSecurity in my webapplication without having to define the filter section in the `web.xml`, but using a Spring handler interceptor which delegates the call to the `FilterChainProxy`, which is `DelegatingFilterProxy` of SpringSecurity.

Basically I wouldn't like to alter the flow of execution of the chain of filters in SpringSecurity but make the request starting from my handler interceptor.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this properly from a handler interceptor, since it has no concept of a `FilterChain`. So you could feed the request into a Spring Security filter chain, but there is no way of passing on the request which it spits out the other end. Since Spring Security uses request wrappers, any functionality which depended on them would be lost. Any integration would have to be done at the dispatcher servlet level.

You might want follow [this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6903) which covers exactly what you're asking for.